# Does Hardy's paradox represent a proof against Bohm's interpretation of the quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, quantum-interpretations, non-locality, bohmian-mechanics

This is a thought-experiment, see "Quantum Mechanics, Local Realistic Theories, and Lorentz-Invariant Realistic Theories", Phys. Rev. Lett., Vol. 68, No. 20, page 2981, year 1992, that rules out local hidden variables. But does it also rule out nonlocal influence of the measurement result of one particle, on the wave-function of another particle, **before** it was measured?
Is this paradox a proof of impossibility of Bohm's interpretation of the quantum mechanics?

[image]

The experiment goes as follows: an electron $e^-$ and a positron $e^+$ land, each one, on a beam-splitter, $BS1^-$ respectively $BS1^+$. One gets the following joint wave-function **of two independent particles**:

$ (1) \ e^+ \to \frac {|v^+> + i|u^+>}{\sqrt (2)} $

$ (2) \ e^- \to \frac {|v^-> + i|u^->}{\sqrt (2)} $

However, the couple $|u^+>|u^->$ **annihilates** at the point P, with production ofgamma rays, s.t. an entanglement appears

$ (3) \ |\psi> = \frac {1}{2} (|v^+>|v^-> + i|u^+>|v^-> + i|v^+>|u^-> + |2\gamma>). $

The "remainder" of the beams of the positron and electron are gathered by the beam-splitters $BS2^-$ and $BS2^+$, at which the following transformations take place.

$ (4) \ |v^±> → \frac {i|c^± > + |d^± >}{\sqrt (2)}, $

$ (5) \ |u^±> → \frac {|c^± > + i|d^± >}{\sqrt (2)} . $

So, in all, we get after $BS2^-$ and $BS2^+$ one gets the following wave-function:

$ (6) \ |\psi> → \frac {1}{4} (−3|c^+>|c^−> + i|c^+>|d^−> + i|d^+>|c^−> − |d^+>|d^−> + |2\gamma>) $.

**There is nothing special until now, unless the experiment is judged by people traveling in opposite frames of coordinates.**

In what follows we are interested in the detections in the detectors $D^+$ and $D^-$.
Let's accompany an analyst that travels in a frame $I^+$ in which the positron is at rest. From his point of view, the positron reaches $BS2^+$ before the electron reaches $BS2^-$, s.t. after the positron reaches $BS2^+$ the wave-function is

$ (7) \ |\psi> = \frac {1}{4}(−|c^+>|u^−> + 2i|c^+>|v^−> + i|d^+>|u^−> + |2\gamma>) .$

According to the before last term, the detection in $D^+$ leaves the electron on the path $u^-$.

But an analyst that travels in the frame $I^-$ in which the electron is at rest, would hold the opposite, i.e. that the electron reaches $BS2^-$ before that positron reaches $BS2^+$, and the following wave-function is bound to appear

$ (8) \ |\psi> = \frac {1}{4}(−|u^+>|c^-> + 2i|v^+>|c^-> + i|u^+>|d^-> + |2\gamma>) .$

So, he holds that after the detection in $D^-$, the positron should have been left on the path $u^+$.

**Here is the problem**: the combination $|u^+>|u^->$ does not exist, it was destroyed into gamma rays. And if the gamma rays appeared, the detections in the detectors $D^±$ and $C^±$ wouldn't be obtained.

Comment: Bohm's interpretation cannot be falsified in an experiment that does not falsify quantum mechanics itself.

Comment: Sofia's reaction: this comment is not rigorously correct. Bohm's interpretation is NOT fully equivalent with the quantum mechanics (QT), it is based on MORE assumptions than QT.

Comment: Yes, but these extra assumptions like the assumption of "quantum equilibrium" cannot be falsified in experiments that are consistent with QM, because you can always assume that these conditions are met. Only the opposite is possible, e.g. where you could see a violation of QM consistent with a Bohmian quantum non-equilibrium situation.

Comment: Sofia's reaction: THIS is the question!!!

Comment: Sofia's reaction (continuation): Are you familiar with Hardy's paradox? It examines a certain experiment with two entangled particles, while judging according to two frames of coordinates in movement. It shows that the predictions for the particles' positions according to one frame, contradict those predicted according to the other frame.

Comment: You didn't discuss the difference in emission time (lower left corner) ... I suppose both are coming from a common point.  But what about length and time contraction of the different paths? You get something like an inferometer.

Comment: @jdlugosz: I apologize, I edited this experiment while explaining it to somebody. The original proposal of Hardy was with a positron and electron, for maximal simplicity. Of course, they enter $BS1^+$ and $BS1^-$ simultaneously, and $BS1^+$ and $BS1^-$ are very, very close, s.t. the simultaneity of the entering of the two particles in these beam-splitters is not affected by judging from different frames. About length and time contraction, your question is good (see continuation).

Comment: I introduce now a modification in the text. An observer travelling with the positron, has the advantage that passing through the two beam-splitters occurs at the same location in his frame, s.t. for him the time interval between visiting the two beam-splitters is shorter than the time-interval for the electron to pass from $BS1^-$ to $BS2^-$.

Comment: Sofia, please take care not to edit your posts too much. Making 3 or 4 edits to a post is fine, but any time it seems like you might have more edits than that, save up your changes and only make an edit when you have a substantial amount of stuff to change. Editing a single post 8 or 10 or more times is usually too much.

Comment: If your detector in $BS1^+$ and $BS1^-$ can discriminate a photon from an electron, then what is the problem ? As far as I understand, you'll conclude that if its a photon, then there is annihilation, if it's a particle, then no annihilation.
Obviously you can always discriminate both by looking at the time it makes to reach your detectors, so what is the problem?

Comment: Since Hardy's paradox involves disagreements over simultaneity, I wonder if Bohm's interpretation been successfully extended to relativistic quantum theory--from what I understood the original version only successfully reproduced the predictions of non-relativistic QM.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : can you open a chat room : "Hardy's paradox vs. Bohm" ? It would be very useful because it is a hot topic according to talks that I have with scientists. Please notify me if and when you do and I will answer you there.

Comment: @Sofia - I wouldn't really have much to contribute on the subject, all I know about Bohmian mechanics is from reading a few non-technical summaries like [this one](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-bohm/), which says in Section 14 that Bohmian mechanics isn't Lorentz-invariant and that there are reasons it would be hard to come up with a Lorentz-invariant analogue of it (but apparently it's been attempted, I found [this thread](http://www.physicsforums.com/threads/bohmian-mechanics-do-photons-travel-faster-than-c-in-double-slit-experiment.313041/) which has some links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I give here is the result of many discussions with experts, and I heard many opinions in all the directions. So, I write here what is known to me by the time that I give this answer.

**1.** There are three interpretations known as the most elaborated, most investigated:

- a) *The standard (or Copenhagen) interpretation + the von Neumann's reduction postulate, which can act non-locally;*
- b) *Bohm's interpretation, that rules out the collapse, and recognizes that entanglements work on a non-local base;*
- c) *GRW (Ghirardi, Rimini and Weber) interpretation that tries to simulate the collapse by modifying the Schrodinger equation, i.e. introducing a stochastic term and non-local potential.*

**2.** As detailed above, the idea that the entanglements resort to some sort of non-local transmission of information between the measured particles, could not be avoided. On top of this problem comes the relativity theory and tells us that space-separated measurements on particles belonging to an entanglement, don't have an absolute time-order. According to some frame of coordinates the particle A is measured first, while according to another frame, in relative movement, the particle B is measured first. This fact opens a question: $$The \ measurement \ of \ one \ of \ particles \ collapses \ the \ entanglement?$$

How can it be possible? There exists frames of coordinates according to which, by the time the above particle is measured, the other particle didn't reach the detector.

$$Then, it \ is \ not \ at \ the \ contact \ with \ a \ macroscopic \ detector \ that \ the \ collapse \ occurs?$$

$$If \ so, \ could \ it \ be \ that \ Bohm's \ interpretation, \ that \ eliminates \ the \ collapse, \ is \ correct?$$

**3.** Hardy's thought experiment (actually performed by Aephraim Steinberg's group), shows that Bohm's interpretation has difficulties with the relativity, as explained in the question. This thought-experiment belongs to the class of ***contextual*** experiments and applies ***counterfactual reasoning***, but Bohm's interpretation is compatible with counter-factual reasoning.

As a consequence, some researchers are inclined to think that the quantum world admits a ***preferred frame***, despite the theory of relativity which refutes such things.

Comment: There is no problem between Bohm's formulation and relativity, except when people applies the non-relativistic version to relativistic domains, but well the same difficulties arise if one was to apply non-relativistic wavefunction or the non-relativistic density matrix formulations to relativistic situations.

Comment: Don't hurry to take celebrated physicists for fools. The fact that the Bohmian mechanics clashes with relativity was widely acknowledged, and first of all by dedicated Bohm's supporters. Nobody said that the wave-function in Hardy's article is a solution of the Schrodinger equation. It may be as well a solution of Dirac's equation. Best regards, Sofia

Comment: Bohmian mechanics has been misunderstood by some of his supporters, but the same happens with other formulations. And being a "celebrated physicist" doesn't avoid one from making mistakes. I recall all the claims about how collapse in Copenhagen formulation violated relativity, until relativistic collapse models showed non-local quantum measurements in agreement with relativity. I don't know any clash of Bohmian mechanics with relativity wasn't a misunderstanding or an attempt to apply the non-relativistic formulation to relativistic domain. Best.

Comment: @juanrga You see, such things as you say, "Bohmian mechanics has been misunderstood by some of his supporters", are just words, in absence of specific examples. Let me tell you the Bohm's formalism was **rigorously** proved to clash with the experiment, even without using moving frames, by Partha Ghose, 16 years ago, and recently by me. But, such a talk of just exchanging general comments leads nowhere. Unfortunately, I am no more an active user of this site. If you are interested in rigorous talk, I can give you another address. Best regards, Sofia

Comment: Really? The same Partha Ghose that now claims that quantum mechanics is an approximation to classical mechanics? About his "rigorous" work on Bohm, I find a glaring mistake already in his equation (3). He doesn't understand ensembles and about trajectories he just reveals to be another critic that misunderstand the theory. He applies fermionic trajectory theory to bosons and claims to find a conflict with experiment. He is wrong.

Comment: @juanrga In which article do you think eq. (3) is wrong? Ghose has many articles. From his two articles proving that BM clashes with experiment, the proof in one of them (arXiv:quant-ph/0103126v8), I obtained by myself, unaware of his proof, so I guarantee that it is correct. His next proof, "On Entangled Multi-Particle Systems in Bohmian Theory", Advanced Sc. Lett., Vol. 2, 97–99, (2009), is even sharper. Another proof of mine, extremely simple, "What is Wrong with Bohm’s Mechanics? An Analysis of a Hong-Ou-Mandel Type Experiment", appears in the J. Mod. Phys., Vol.7 No.10 2016.

Comment: @juanrga About mixing between fermions and bosons, I didn't see that he did such a thing, where is it, in which article?