# Does the difference between contextuality, nonlocality and retrocausality depend on where we draw the boundaries?

Tags: quantum-interpretations

Suppose we have a quantum system and a measuring apparatus in a superposition of detector settings. Different detector settings would measure "complementary" properties of the quantum system. The act of measurement will occur at time $t_m$.

We need to draw a boundary between the system and the environment. There are boundaries in space, as well as a future boundary in time (think *spacetime* and *histories*).

If the apparatus lies outside the boundary, we have contextuality. If the apparatus lies inside the boundary, but the "final time" boundary occurs at $t_f < t_m$, we have nonlocality between the detector settings and the hidden state. If the apparatus is inside, and $t_f > t_m$, we have "delayed choice" retrocausality from the measurement to the earlier hidden state.

So, it depends *contextually* upon where we draw the *arbitrary unphysical* boundary.

Boundary = Heisenberg cut

Is this a valid "interpretation"?

Comment: Please, try to be more precise. It's not obvious to understand what you *really* mean. Contextuality, non locality, and retrocausality are just a form of counterfactuality. That is, the final result you effectively measure depends on what was possible.

Comment: Nope, this is plain nonsense.

Comment: I understand the question, as I worked with contextuality problems for a long time. I can reformulate the question. The question poster is simply confused about the concept of contextuality. I strongly recommend the question to be seen by the community, the concept of contextuality is important in the quantum theory and I saw, in other questions, that it would have been helpful if this concept were known.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Ignoring the part a about retrocausality, the question is if quantum contextuality is a consequence of entanglement with an environment that lies beyond the Heisenberg cut. Makes sense to me...

Comment: @JohnRennie: Here is my proposal for making the question clear: $$ $$ What means contextuality? What is the relationship between the following concepts: contextuality, retrodiction, the situation that a classical measurement was performed. Is it relevant where exactly we place, at our wish, a Heisenberg cut? An example would be of help."

Comment: @Christoph: Let us know when you have found a way to make a "Heisenberg cut" between two quarks...

Comment: @CuriousOne: quarks have nothing to do with the question. Since you recommended to put the question on hold, and since I suggested a better formulation, I invite you to see my formulation. I insist, it is a useful question, once clearly formulated.

Comment: @Sofia: So you can tell me how I can make a Heisenberg cut between two quarks in my experiment? Cool! Shall we chat, again?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I am gladly at your service, as you know. My own problem is that there are hours when I can't be at the computer because my different duties. But, let me tell you something that I saw until now. The issue of contextuality is practically absent from questions, and I see in answers that the knowledge of this instrument, contextuality, would be of much help. So, I offer my help about that.

Comment: @Sofia: I will refer you to Lubos Motl's opinions about all of this. He frequently compares the intellectual content of these things (which are merely endless reformulations of what we teach in QM 101 anyway) with the biological end products of the mammalian digestive system. I agree with him 100%. Unless any of this produces new physics it's just endless mental circles around an eighty year old discovery.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I would gladly look at those opinions, but, I learned contextuality from Peres, Mermin, Shimony. They were my teachers. And **I have, by myself, articles** on this issue. In your last statement, you have a mistake. The first **famous** and simply understandable examples of contextuality are due to Hardy and to Greenberger, Horne and Zeilinger. The Hardy's is from 1992-1993, and the GHZ from cca. 1990 . Abner Shimony when came to us in a visit, explained it. It's not 80 years.

Comment: @CuriousOne: but now, I become unavailable for a couple of hours. Meanwhile, you can read my answer to the question, but if something is not clear, I will be available later.

Comment: @Sofia: So which of these experiments contradict standard QM? None, right? So it's still the same old, same old after 80 years.

Comment: @CuriousOne: major experiments on decoherence where not performed until the 80s

Comment: @Christoph: What have we learned from these experiments that contradicts standard QM?

Comment: @CuriousOne: no contradictions, but fairly important clarifications (your claim was that we haven't learned anything since the 30s); your buddy Luboš has written multiple times about this subject, eg [this article](http://motls.blogspot.de/2009/09/schrodinger-virus-and-decoherence.html) (take note of the paragraph *Limitations of the Copenhagen interpretation*)

Comment: @Christoph: So what has been clarified that was not already covered by standard QM? Please give an example. I fail to see, by the way, why Copenhagen shouldn't cover decoherence. It's implied in the linearity of the equations and folks in solid state physics have been using it for a long time without making any fuss about it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: What was missing from Luboš exposition? Without decoherence, the Copenhagen interpretation is more religion than physics. Also note some more steps along the way towards a fuller understanding of QM that happened after the 30s: We got the path integral in the 40s, Gleason's theorem in the 50s, Bell's theorem in the 60s, the Lindblad equation in the 70s, decoherence experiments in the 80s, Shor's algorithm in the 90s, ...

Comment: @Christoph: Then all of science is religion, and you just didn't know that you were religious. Newton differs in NOTHING from the ontology of QM. Classical mechanics gives you a recipe to calculate physical systems, you calculate and it's good (within the limits of the theory). QM gives you a recipe to calculate physical systems, you calculate and it's all good (within the limits of the theory). You may not have noticed that, but that's how all of physics works.

Comment: @Christoph: I do know the history of QM, but the path integral is not actually QM, it's just one perturbation Ansatz (and not a good one). Feynman himself warned us to see more physics in it than is contained in it. The remainder on your list is superfluous mysticism that has added absolutely nothing to QM as a physical theory.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know until now what is the "Heisenberg cut". So, I cite here what I found in Wikipedia.

"*In quantum mechanics, a Heisenberg cut is the hypothetical interface between quantum events and an observer's information, knowledge, or conscious awareness. Below the cut everything is governed by the wave function; above the cut a classical description is used. The Heisenberg cut is a theoretical construct; it is not known whether actual Heisenberg cuts exist, where they might be found, or how they could be detected experimentally*."

I will use the above definition of "Heisenberg cut".

Now, oncept of contextuality, or contextual experiments is clearly explained in "Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods", by A. Peres, Kluwer Academic Publishers, Chapter 7.

Let an operator **A** commute with two other operators, **B** and **C**, but **B** doesn't commute with **C**. One can measure **A** together with **B**, or together with **C**. If the result of the measurement of **A** depends on its context, namely on whether we measure **A** together with **B**, or together with **C**, the experiment is said to be contextual.

Thus, the concept of contextuality involves at least three observables.

Another thing: we can't place the *Heisenberg cut* wherever we please. It's not up to us to decide where and when the collapse occurred. Only when an actual measurement with a macroscopic apparatus is done, we can say that the effect of getting **one** result out of the different possibility, occurred. We can't say more than that.

*Retrodiction*: **forbidden**, leads to contradiction. See my example with Hardy's thought experiment, [Does Hardy's paradox represent a proof against Bohm's interpretation of the quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145569/does-hardys-paradox-represent-a-proof-against-bohms-interpretation-of-the-quan)

Comment: What do you mean by together? To measure $AB$ means to measure $A$ and $B$ at the same time, but its also the same thing as measuring the operator $D = AB$. If they commute, then obviously you can have this interpretation of "at the same time", but what does "the result of the measurement of $A$ depend on its context" means ? Please, add some formula or formalism so we can get it.

Comment: Moreover, I would add that in my opinion, the concept of Heisenberg cut is nothing new and is irrelevant. A cut should be interpreted as a system identification rather than "classical against quantum". For example, because the interaction of two systems takes place in the tensor product of the two Hilbert spaces, a cut, seen from the observer, would be to consider that you have two systems interacting instead of one tensor product.

Comment: @sure: as I see from your question, you didn't look at the examples that I quote in the answer. Theorems get a better meaning when we look at examples, otherwise a discussion is in generalities, with little chance for elucidation. In the examples, A is measured on **one particle** and **B** (or **C**) on **another particle**. Moreover, the concept of Heisenberg cut is **very relevant**, but you would see that in the examples. What I said and repeat, the cut has to be placed where **really it is**. Otherwise we come to contradictions.